# Max frequency that can be measured with Arduino Atmega2560

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, frequency-measurement

For the school project I must measure frequency with Arduino Atmega2560 (or some other microcontroller). The idea is to have timer interrupt set to 1 second and external square signal (frequency) connected to pin interrupt. Each interrupt on pin increment counter for 1. Every second (timer interrupt) the frequency is calculated and counter is reset to 0. The frequency I must measure vary from 2-11 kHz. Can this be done?

regards

Comment: what is your clock frequency, and interrupt latency?

Comment: Gut feeling: easily. For higher frequencies it might be better to use a counter/timer to count the pulses directly.

Comment: I think the clock frequency is 12Mhz or 16Mhz (must verify)..

Comment: You can measure frequencies all the way up to 8 MHz (perhaps even up to 16 MHz, I can't remember) by using timer/counter 2 as an externally clocked counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arduino ATMega2650 is listed as having a clock speed of 16MHz, meaning that it should be able to handle this at least in terms of instruction cycles. If you look at the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) (P.39) for the actual ATMega2650 chip it appears the I/O clock runs at the same speed as the CPU clock.

There is also this [forum post](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=4324.0) where someone found the maximum digital write speed to be around 100kHz.

I'd say go for it. The chip should be able to handle this. The only place you might run into issues is if you try to do too much in your 1 second timer interrupt, but if all you are doing is returning the counter value then resetting you should be fine.